# Invalid argument type

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile my code but I keep getting this error.

```
error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct packet')
```

Parts of the initialization:

```
struct list *current;
struct packet p;

struct packet *newpacket = malloc(sizeof(p));
```

This line is causing the error, but I don't know what's wrong.

```
if ((current -> p -> block_num < newpacket -> block_num) && (current -> next -> p -> block_num > newpacket -> block_num)){
```

My header files:

```
struct packet {
unsigned short  block_num;
unsigned short  block_size;
unsigned short  crc;
unsigned char  *payload;
};

struct list {
struct packet p;
struct list *next;
};
```

I don't understand what's wrong, and I'm really new to C. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The member `p` of `list` is not a pointer, so it should be `current->p.block_num` etc...

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator is used in instances where you have a pointer to an object and want to access the objects members. In this case, you have an instance to a packet structure which is not a pointer. You are trying to access its members with the `->` operator. This is **incorrect**. Instead you should use the `.` operator.

For example: `current->p.block_num` would give you the packet block number.

The following is described in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++):

- `a->b` is known as a structure dereference (member `b` of object pointed to by `a`).
- `a.b` is known as a structure reference (member `b` of object `a`).

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by incorrectly dereferencing of the `p` element in `current -> next -> p -> block_num` and `current -> p -> block_num`.

They should be `current -> p.block_num` and `current -> p.block_num`, respectively.

Notice that you declare `p` in `struct list` as `struct packet p;`  not as `struct packet *p;`.

That means that the two references in the left side of each comparison are actual structs, not pointers to structs.